# What is LastCall for in RhinoMocks? 

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rhino-mocks

What is the use of `lastcall` method in rhino mock?
Can you please explain with the help of example?

Answer (score 1):

LastCall allows you to do something additional to the last call that was added.

```
Expect.Call(delegate{ mockObject.DoSomething("foo"); }).IgnoreArguments();
```

is that same as

```
mockObject.DoSomething("foo"); 
LastCall.IgnoreArguments();
```

Hope this helps.